# Issue with cargo test and ink! Flipper contract

Tags: ink, cargo, cargo-contract

`cargo contract build` works just fine and produces the correct outputs in the /target folder.

Running `cargo test` however throws the following error:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `wasm-opt-sys v0.113.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/test_user/Dev/INK/flipper/target/debug/build/wasm-opt-sys-3a19b50779e5ebb2/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-apple-darwin")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-apple-darwin")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64-apple-darwin
  CXX_x86_64-apple-darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64_apple_darwin
  CXX_x86_64_apple_darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXX
  HOST_CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX
  CXX = None
  running: "c++" "--version"
  exit status: 0
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  RUSTC = Some("/Users/test_user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/rustc")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64-apple-darwin
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-apple-darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64_apple_darwin
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_apple_darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXXFLAGS
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS
  CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:CXXBRIDGE_PREFIX=wasm-opt-sys
  cargo:CXXBRIDGE_LINKS=binaryen
  cargo:CXXBRIDGE_DIR0=/Users/test_user/Dev/INK/flipper/target/debug/build/wasm-opt-sys-029508906017695d/out/cxxbridge/include
  cargo:CXXBRIDGE_DIR1=/Users/test_user/Dev/INK/flipper/target/debug/build/wasm-opt-sys-029508906017695d/out/cxxbridge/crate
  cargo:CXXBRIDGE_DIR2=/Users/test_user/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/wasm-opt-sys-0.113.0/binaryen/src
  cargo:CXXBRIDGE_DIR3=/Users/test_user/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/wasm-opt-sys-0.113.0/binaryen/src/tools
  cargo:CXXBRIDGE_DIR4=/Users/test_user/Dev/INK/flipper/target/debug/build/wasm-opt-sys-029508906017695d/out
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-apple-darwin")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-apple-darwin")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64-apple-darwin
  CXX_x86_64-apple-darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64_apple_darwin
  CXX_x86_64_apple_darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXX
  HOST_CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX
  CXX = None
  running: "c++" "--version"
  exit status: 0
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  RUSTC = Some("/Users/test_user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/rustc")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64-apple-darwin
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-apple-darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64_apple_darwin
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_apple_darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXXFLAGS
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS
  CXXFLAGS = None
  running: "c++" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "--target=x86_64-apple-darwin" "-mmacosx-version-min=10.7" "-I" "/Users/test_user/Dev/INK/flipper/target/debug/build/wasm-opt-sys-029508906017695d/out/cxxbridge/include" "-I" "/Users/test_user/Dev/INK/flipper/target/debug/build/wasm-opt-sys-029508906017695d/out/cxxbridge/crate" "-I" "/Users/test_user/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/wasm-opt-sys-0.113.0/binaryen/src" "-I" "/Users/test_user/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/wasm-opt-sys-0.113.0/binaryen/src/tools" "-I" "/Users/test_user/Dev/INK/flipper/target/debug/build/wasm-opt-sys-029508906017695d/out" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-DTHROW_ON_FATAL" "-o" "/Users/test_user/Dev/INK/flipper/target/debug/build/wasm-opt-sys-029508906017695d/out/fc3ac4579f2123d0-lib.rs.o" "-c" "/Users/test_user/Dev/INK/flipper/target/debug/build/wasm-opt-sys-029508906017695d/out/cxxbridge/sources/wasm-opt-sys/src/lib.rs.cc"
```

The error looks like above looks like it's related to the C++ compiler but I've got another older ink! flipper contract on my machine where `cargo test` works just fine.

Has anyone got any ideas what could be the issue?

```
cargo contract --version
cargo-contract-contract 3.2.0-unknown-x86_64-apple-darwin

rustc --version
rustc 1.73.0 (cc66ad468 2023-10-03)
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the issue was that the build scripts that were running during compilation were by default targeting `-mmacosx-version-min=10.7` which meant that some features were not available.

The fix was to add the following environment variable:

`export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.13`